# How to add a third piece to a "Case" statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that checks a for voided invoices and if they were re-tendered.  We do not allow "quicksales" to be re-tendered there for if a quicksale is voided my query goes haywire.  What i'd like to do is if a "quicksale" has been voided... in the retendered field display "QuickSale" it should also not check to see if the invoice has been retendered as we do not allow it.  My query is below and the t1.Register_Transaction_Type column is what we will search to see if "Quick" is the type.  All other transactions are fine.

```
SELECT        
  t1.Store_Number, 
  t1.Invoice_Number, 
  t1.Invoice_Date, 
  t1.Vehicle_Tag, 
  t1.Void_Reason, 
  vt1.Invoice_Total, 
  t2.Invoice_Number AS [New Invoice #], 
  t2.Vehicle_Tag AS [Vehicle Tag], 
  t2.Invoice_Total AS [New Invoice Total], 
  CASE 
    WHEN t2.Vehicle_Tag IS NULL THEN 'NO'
    WHEN t1.register_transaction_type = 'QUICK' THEN 'Quicksale'
    ELSE 'YES'
  END AS [Re-tendered?], 
  User_Tb.User_Name, 
  t1.Register_Transaction_Type
FROM            
  Invoice_Tb AS t1 
  INNER JOIN Employee_Tb 
    ON t1.Void_Employee_Tax_Payer_Id = Employee_Tb.Tax_Payer_Id 
  INNER JOIN User_Tb 
    ON Employee_Tb.User_Id = User_Tb.User_Id 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Invoice_Tb AS t2 
    ON t1.Vehicle_Tag = t2.Vehicle_Tag AND 
       t2.Void_Flag = 'n' AND 
       t2.Invoice_Date >= DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) AND
       t2.Invoice_Date < DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
WHERE        
  (t1.Void_Flag = 'y') AND 
  (t1.Invoice_Date >= DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)) 
  AND (t1.Invoice_Date < DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()),0)) 
  AND (t1.Store_Number = '2')
ORDER BY t1.Store_Number, t1.Invoice_Date
```

Below is an example of what I'm getting:  as you can see it's just dumping invoices it's not linked to...

```
-- -------  ---------------------  ------  -------  -------  -------  ---------  ----
2  3******  12/5/2012 12:00:00 AM  REFUND  54.9900  3******  52.9000  Quicksale  user
2  3******  12/5/2012 12:00:00 AM  REFUND  54.9900  3******  59.9800  Quicksale  user
2  3******  12/5/2012 12:00:00 AM  REFUND  54.9900  3******  24.9900  Quicksale  user
```

Comment: I can't even spot that column you mention in that messy SQL. You might want to fix the formatting first (I wouldn't be surprised if you saw the solution yourself then)

Comment: The query could use a few more line breaks than are currently present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking for this?

```
CASE
  WHEN t1.Register_Transaction_Type = 'Quick' THEN 'QuickSale'
  WHEN t2.Vehicle_Tag IS NULL THEN 'NO'
  ELSE 'YES'
  END AS [Re-tendered?]
```

It might help if you could provide a small table showing the logic you have in mind, i.e. for this combination of column values I would like this assortment of output values.

Comment: See above.  I edited my query that has included the "transaction type"  It shows as a "quicksale".  I also included the "output" you will see it keeps grabbing more invoices that it was not retendered as.  It should just list the initial invoice and say "quicksale, and not list any other invoice information.

Comment: @Shmewnix - Sorry, but your sample output is not does not enlighten those of use who cannot see the input nor divine what you want.  How are invoices linked to one another?  Are you trying to break the `OUTER JOIN` between `T1` and `T2` based on some condition?

Comment: `... LEFT OUTER JOIN Invoice_Tb AS t2 ON t1.Register_Transaction_Type != 'Quick' AND...`?

Answer (score 3):

```
-- code
CASE
    WHEN t2.Vehicle_Tag IS NULL THEN 'NO'
    WHEN [COLUMN] IS [CONDITION]
    -- ...
    ELSE 'YES'
END AS [Re-tendered?]
```

Comment: that works great for adding the "Quicksale", however it still searches for the "retender" of the invoice displaying 30 results.  It should only display 1.

Comment: You can add an AND clause within the WHEN syntax.